# OCI Policy to allow group to manage object-family is not applied

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create a simple policy for a user to access object-family however no matter what I try is not working.  Basically, I add a user and write a policy to manage object-family.

I have created a compartment named: ops-compartment

[image]

I have created a dev domain within ops-compartment named dev and then Created group 'dev/OS' (again) within ops-compartment. Lastly, I created user "user2" under dev domain and added to group 'dev/OS'

[image]

I wrote the following policy in ops-compartment

```
Allow group 'dev/OS' to manage object-family in compartment 'ops-compartment'
```

Unfortunately this is not working. The user "user2" cannot even see/access the compartment.

[image]

Any idea why this policy is not working?